# How to flag external plagiarism

Tags: support, plagiarism, external-links

I have seen the questions and answers relating to plagiarism but they all address answers on SO that have been plagiarized from external sites.  But I have not found any information about the reverse, i.e. questions and/or answers lifted verbatim from SO and posted on other sites.

This question ([SO 39494058](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable)) has been plagiarized by an external site, here:
[External Site](https://icevanila.com/question/behaviorsubject-vs-observable)

[Another site](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/03/angular2-difference-between-a-behavior-subject-and-an-observable/) has done the same but has at least provided additional commentary and attribution to the author.

How should this be reported?  I am assuming flagging the question is not enough?

Comment: Moderators can’t do anything about external sites, so flagging would be pointless. Note that the license permits republishing, provided proper attribution is provided.